# how to recognize Previous activity which is already finished

Tags: android, android-activity

is there a way to recognize Previous activity which is already finished?

for example if activity B was called by activity A and before calling,Activity A has finished, can I recognize which activity called Activity B?

Comment: `"can I recognize which activity called Activity B"` no, what do you need it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `intent.putExtra()`

In `ActivityA` write below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("ActivityName",ActivityA.class.getSimpleName());
startActivity(intent);
```

In `ActivityB` of `onCreate()`:

```
String activityName = getIntent().getStringExtra("ActivityName");
```